# Actionscript 2 particles

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I know this is old technology but I just want to an update to a flash xmas card I send out. Basically I use particles script (found below) that follows my mouse and spews out some gold particles. I would like to object this some how so that it follows behind an tweened object that goes across the screen . I was thinking it might be a case of changing the event listener to something but cant figure it out.

EDIT - My object is a movieclip called sleigh

Any help appreciated.

**Script** (AS2)

```
//import bitmap class
import flash.display.BitmapData;

//Settings
var particleMaxSpeed:Number = 3;
var particleFadeSpeed:Number = 5;
var particleTotal:Number = 5;
var particleRange:Number = 25;

/**
 * createExplosion(target X position, target Y position)
 */
function createExplosion(targetX:Number, targetY:Number):Void
{
    //run for loop based on particleTotal
    for (var i:Number = 0; i<particleTotal; i++) {
        //attach bitmap from the library with the linked name "adobe_flash"
        var myBmp:BitmapData = BitmapData.loadBitmap("fire.jpg");

        //create the "main_holder" movieclip that will hold our bitmap
        var particle_mc = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("main_holder", _root.getNextHighestDepth());

        //create an "internal_holder" movieclip inside "main_holder" that we'll use to center the bitmap data
        var internal_holder:MovieClip = particle_mc.createEmptyMovieClip("internal_holder", particle_mc.getNextHighestDepth());

        //set "internal_holder" x and y position based on bitmap size
        internal_holder._x = -myBmp.width/2;
        internal_holder._y = -myBmp.height/2;   

        //finally, attach the bitmapData "myBmp" to the movieclip "internal_holder"
        internal_holder.attachBitmap(myBmp, internal_holder.getNextHighestDepth(), "never", true); 

        //set position & rotation, alpha
        particle_mc._x = targetX
        particle_mc._y = targetY
        particle_mc._rotation = random(360);
        particle_mc._alpha = random(50)+50;

        //set particle boundry            
        particle_mc.boundyLeft = targetX - particleRange;
        particle_mc.boundyTop = targetY - particleRange;
        particle_mc.boundyRight = targetX + particleRange;
        particle_mc.boundyBottom = targetY + particleRange;

        //set speed/direction of fragment
        particle_mc.speedX = Math.random(particleMaxSpeed)-Math.random(particleMaxSpeed);
        particle_mc.speedY = Math.random(particleMaxSpeed)-Math.random(particleMaxSpeed);
        particle_mc.speedX *= particleMaxSpeed
        particle_mc.speedY *= particleMaxSpeed

        //set fade out speed
        particle_mc.fadeSpeed = Math.random(particleFadeSpeed)*particleFadeSpeed;

        //just a visual particle counter
        numberOfParticles++;

        //make fragment move using onEnterFrame
        particle_mc.onEnterFrame = function():Void 
        {
            //update alpha, x, y
            this._alpha -= this.fadeSpeed;
            this._x += this.speedX;
            this._y += this.speedY;
            //if fragment is invisible or out of bounds, remove it
            if (this._alpha <= 0 || this._x < this.boundyLeft || this._x > this.boundyRight || this._y < this.boundyTop || this._y > this.boundyBottom) 
            {
                this.removeMovieClip();
                //
                numberOfParticles--;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
* Mouse Controls
*/
//create an object that we'll listen to
mouseListener = new Object();

//on Click, createExplosion
mouseListener.onMouseDown = function() {
    //createExplosion(_xmouse, _ymouse);
}
mouseListener.onMouseMove = function() {
    createExplosion(_xmouse, _ymouse);
}

//add listener
Mouse.addListener(mouseListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `createExplosion` function every frame and pass it the `sleigh` x and y coordinates instead of the mouse coordinates. Replace

```
mouseListener.onMouseMove = function() {
    createExplosion(_xmouse, _ymouse);
}
```

with

```
sleigh.onEnterFrame = function() {
    createExplosion(sleigh._x, sleigh._y);
}
```

and remove the other mouse listener stuff